# Clicking noise in digital piano should i return it?

Tags: maintenance, digital-piano

I am learning piano and music theory for the first time. I got a Casio privia px 150 -  it was recommended everywhere. I especially liked the weighted keys. But then today I noticed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peErWl2n1eA) and recorded it.

The clicking noise is only heard when piano is on low to medium volume and does not really affect the playing experience. If I decide to keep the piano instead of returning it, would it affect my learning experience in the long run?

Comment: We have an electric piano that after a few years suffered this problem. The felt under the keys was not continuous, and over time it got compressed to the point where one of the keys would slide between the two felt portions and hit the board underneath. We've had the felt replaced twice over the past 5-6 years or so.

Comment: Had a Celviano with notes that developed a clickety clackety sound when hit at a slight angle. Not even 10 years old, well worn, and subjected to hot/cold ambient temperatures. No place for it but the tip, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should get it sorted - presuming you brought the piano from somewhere with a warranty. It should be repairable, rather than you needing to return it completely.

Digital pianos have various felt parts which prevent wood/metal parts making contact - and producing the clicking noise you can hear on that key. They're completely replaceable - a new (or refurbished?) piano shouldn't have that problem.

> Would affect my learning experience in the long run?

Well...probably not, but that clicking will be irritating as hell, and I imagine you'd be able to hear it if you were ever to perform a more mellow piece.

Comment: thanks for the response I will return it then, since i bought it online there is no other option